# How can I dynamically create an endpoints ResourceContainer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

So using Google Cloud Endpoints, we can create a custom request message and create a endpoints.ResourceContainer from it, like this:

```py
Test_Resource = endpoints.ResourceContainer(message_types.VoidMessage, 
                                   param1=messages.IntegerField(2, required=False),
                                   param2=messages.StringField(3, required=False))
```

And then later on use that in our endpoints.method

```py
@endpoints.method(Test_Resource, MessageCommon, path='list', http_method='POST', name='list')
    def model_list(self, request):
        pass
```

My question is that is there any way that we can dynamically create the ResourceContainer by passing a dictionary contains messages types. Something like a factory to create ResourceContainer:

```py
def get_resource_container(messageCls, dict):
    new_rc = endpoints.ResourceContainer(messageCls) 
    # How do I add in the dict's properties to the ResourceContainer here
    # ...
    return new_rc
```

This will help not to create new Message class every time. We can keep reuse the same base class:

```py
Test_RC2 = get_resource_container(message.types.VoidMessage, dict)
@endpoints.method(Test_RC2, MessageCommon, path='list', http_method='POST', name='list')
    def model_list(self, request):
        pass
```

I tried to search the detail of ResourceContainer but seems like none is available.
Is this possible at all ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform a dict to a list of named parameters you can do : `endpoints.ResourceContainer(messageCls, **dict)`